# Create an Array recursively

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement a recursive Function which returns an array of functions by filling it recursively

```
//arr = [1..1000]
//arr2 = [1,2,3]
function divideToSmallerTasks(arr, arr2) {
    let arrLength = arr.length;
    if (arr === undefined || arrLength == 0) {
        return [];
    } else if (arrLength > 100) {
        return (getRelatedGames(arr.slice(0, 100), arr2)).push(divideToSmallerTasks(arr.slice(100, arrLength), arr2));
    } else {
        return (getRelatedGames(arr, arr2).push(divideToSmallerTasks([], arr2));
}
```

I expected to get back an array of functions `smallerTasks = [function(arr[1..100],arr2[1,2,3]),function(arr[100,..200],arr2[1,2,3]),...]` so I can run them in parallel later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is invoking the `getRelatedGames` function immediately as part of `divideToSmallerTasks`. What you want to do is create an anonymous function which, when executed, will run getRelatedGames as you stated, and return that. Something closer to the following: (untested)

```
function divideToSmallerTasks(arr,arr2){
        let arrLength = arr.length;
        if(arr === undefined || arrLength == 0){             
             return [];
        }else if(arrLength > 100) {
             let result = divideToSmallerTasks(arr.slice(100,arrLength),arr2);
             result.push(function () { return getRelatedGames(arr,arr2); });
             return result;
        }else{
             return [function () { return getRelatedGames(arr,arr2); }]
;}
```

This should result in a list of functions that you can execute one by one whenever you wish and perform the expected getRelatedGames call.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return an array, instead of a new length, which is returned by `push`.

If you do not get a closure, you could add a function which calls `getRelatedGames` later. Here, this function is replaced with `console.log`.

```js
function divideToSmallerTasks(arr, arr2) {
    const defer = (fn, ...args) => () => fn(...args);

    let arrLength = arr.length;

    if (arr === undefined || !arrLength) {
        return [];
    }

    if (arrLength > 3) {
        return [defer(console.log, arr.slice(0, 3), arr2), ...divideToSmallerTasks(arr.slice(3, arrLength), arr2)];
    }

    return [defer(console.log, arr, arr2)];
}

var array = divideToSmallerTasks([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], ['a', 'b', 'c']);

console.log(array);

array.forEach(fn => fn());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```